# Error building catkin on Pandaboard ES (Groovy)

Tags: catkin, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm fairly new to Linux and ROS. I'm trying to install Groovy onto my Pandaboard ES running Ubuntu 12.04. Upon building the catkin packages I get the following errors. I have followed both of the instructions in the links below with no success yet .

Thanks in advance!

```
<== Finished processing package [89 of 147]: 'sensor_msgs'
==> Processing catkin package: 'camera_calibration_parsers'
==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/groovy/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/camera_calibration_parsers' 
==> make -j2 -l2 in '/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/camera_calibration_parsers'
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/camera_calibration_parsers.dir/src/parse_yml.cpp.o
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp: In function ‘void camera_calibration_parsers::operator>>(const YAML::Node&, camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&)’:
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:87:19: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘YAML::Node::operator[](const Key&) const [with Key = char [5]]((*"rows")) >> rows’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:87:19: note: candidate is:
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:84:6: note: void camera_calibration_parsers::operator>>(const YAML::Node&, camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&)
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:84:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘int’ to ‘camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:89:19: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘YAML::Node::operator[](const Key&) const [with Key = char [5]]((*"cols")) >> cols’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:89:19: note: candidate is:
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:84:6: note: void camera_calibration_parsers::operator>>(const YAML::Node&, camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&)
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:84:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘int’ to ‘camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:93:24: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘YAML::Node::operator[](const Key&) const [with Key = int]((*(const int*)(& i))) >> *(m.camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix::data + ((unsigned int)(((unsigned int)i) * 8u)))’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:93:24: note: candidate is:
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:84:6: note: void camera_calibration_parsers::operator>>(const YAML::Node&, camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&)
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:84:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘double’ to ‘camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp: In function ‘bool camera_calibration_parsers::readCalibrationYml(std::istream&, std::string&, sensor_msgs::CameraInfo&)’:
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:153:12: error: ‘class YAML::Parser’ has no member named ‘GetNextDocument’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:155:43: error: ‘class YAML::Node’ has no member named ‘FindValue’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:156:21: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘* name_node >> camera_name’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:156:21: note: candidates are:
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:84:6: note: void camera_calibration_parsers::operator>>(const YAML::Node&, camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&)
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:84:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/complex:488:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::complex<_Tp>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iomanip:229:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setw)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iomanip:199:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setprecision)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iomanip:169:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setfill<_CharT>)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iomanip:131:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setbase)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iomanip:100:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setiosflags)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iomanip:70:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Resetiosflags)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:761:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:756:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:714:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:709:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/istream.tcc:925:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/istream.tcc:957:5: note: template<class _CharT2, class _Traits2> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT2*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:998:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:160:37: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘YAML::Node::operator[](const Key&) [with Key = char [12]]((* & camera_calibration_parsers::WIDTH_YML_NAME)) >> cam_info.sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> >::width’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:160:37: note: candidate is:
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:84:6: note: void camera_calibration_parsers::operator>>(const YAML::Node&, camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&)
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:84:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> >::_width_type {aka unsigned int}’ to ‘camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:161:38: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘YAML::Node::operator[](const Key&) [with Key = char [13]]((* & camera_calibration_parsers::HEIGHT_YML_NAME)) >> cam_info.sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> >::height’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:161:38: note: candidate is:
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:84:6: note: void camera_calibration_parsers::operator>>(const YAML::Node&, camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&)
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:84:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> >::_height_type {aka unsigned int}’ to ‘camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:172:44: error: ‘class YAML::Node’ has no member named ‘FindValue’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:173:31: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘* model_node >> cam_info.sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> >::distortion_model’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:173:31: note: candidates are:
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:84:6: note: void camera_calibration_parsers::operator>>(const YAML::Node&, camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&)
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:84:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> >::_distortion_model_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/complex:488:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::complex<_Tp>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iomanip:229:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setw)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iomanip:199:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setprecision)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iomanip:169:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setfill<_CharT>)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iomanip:131:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setbase)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iomanip:100:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setiosflags)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iomanip:70:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Resetiosflags)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:761:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:756:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:714:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:709:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/istream.tcc:925:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/istream.tcc:957:5: note: template<class _CharT2, class _Traits2> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT2*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:998:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:182:23: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘YAML::Node::operator[](const Key&) const [with Key = char [5]]((*"rows")) >> D_rows’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:182:23: note: candidate is:
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:84:6: note: void camera_calibration_parsers::operator>>(const YAML::Node&, camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&)
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:84:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘int’ to ‘camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:183:23: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘YAML::Node::operator[](const Key&) const [with Key = char [5]]((*"cols")) >> D_cols’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:183:23: note: candidate is:
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:84:6: note: void camera_calibration_parsers::operator>>(const YAML::Node&, camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&)
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:84:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘int’ to ‘camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:187:32: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘YAML::Node::operator[](const Key&) const [with Key = int]((*(const int*)(& i))) >> cam_info.sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> >::D.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = double, _Alloc = std::allocator<double>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference = double&, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int](((unsigned int)i))’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:187:32: note: candidate is:
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:84:6: note: void camera_calibration_parsers::operator>>(const YAML::Node&, camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&)
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:84:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘double’ to ‘camera_calibration_parsers::SimpleMatrix&’
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/camera_calibration_parsers.dir/src/parse_yml.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/camera_calibration_parsers.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 658, in build_workspace_isolated
    number=index + 1, of=len(ordered_packages)
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 443, in build_package
    install, jobs, force_cmake, quiet, last_env, cmake_args, make_args
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 297, in build_catkin_package
    run_command(make_cmd, build_dir, quiet)
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 186, in run_command
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, ' '.join(cmd))
CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/ros/groovy/env.sh make -j2 -l2' returned non-zero exit status 2
<== Failed to process package 'camera_calibration_parsers': 
  Command '/opt/ros/groovy/env.sh make -j2 -l2' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> /opt/ros/groovy/env.sh make -j2 -l2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62083/error-building-catkin-on-pandaboard-es-(groovy)/) by [ferre](https://answers.ros.org/users/4789/ferre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-05-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ferre](https://answers.ros.org/users/4789/ferre/) on 2013-05-03**:
the links to the instructions I followed are: http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/PandaBoard/Source and http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Raspbian/Source

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-05-05**:
Please edit your question include the lines prior to these.  They contain the actual error.

**Comment by [ferre](https://answers.ros.org/users/4789/ferre/) on 2013-05-06**:
@zumili, do you have any thoughts?

**Comment by [ferre](https://answers.ros.org/users/4789/ferre/) on 2013-05-06**:
@tfoote, let me know if the edit helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you can, try using the ARM debs instead of building from source. I've been quite happy with them on my Pandaboard: http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/UbuntuARM

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ferre](https://answers.ros.org/users/4789/ferre/) on 2013-05-06**:
Hi ahendrix, thanks for the tip. So far ros-groovy-ros-base installed without problems. However after following point 4 of http://tinyurl.com/bp5tdjp I get sudo: catkin_init_workspace: command not found even though I confirmed I have ros-groovy-catkin installed. Any ideas?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-06**:
@ferre it sounds like you are doing something like `sudo catkin_init_workspace ...` which will not work because your sudo environment has not done `source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash`. I would highly discourage you from using `sudo` to build source code...

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-06**:
But... you can work around this by doing something like this: `sudo bash` and then your command, `catkin_init_workspace ...`

**Comment by [ferre](https://answers.ros.org/users/4789/ferre/) on 2013-05-07**:
@William thanks for the advice, it is up and running! Fantastic! Just wondering about why not using sudo to build source code?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-07**:
You should really avoid running with `sudo` when ever possible, it's dangerous, for example `sudo rm -rf build/` can easily become `sudo rm -rf build /` on accident.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-07**:
+1 Also, `sudo` leaves build files around that you cannot change, and does not use your carefully-constructed ROS environment.

**Comment by [ferre](https://answers.ros.org/users/4789/ferre/) on 2013-05-07**:
Thanks for the explanation. I wasn't aware of that and spent quite a while trying to build ROS from source. Lessons to take home: 1. installing ROS in the Pandaboard ES with the instructions @ahendrix provided. 2. work as SU instead of using sudo to avoid undesirable behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like a version mismatch of yaml-cpp (it recently updated to 0.5 and is not backwards compatible with 0.3).

Can you post the version of yaml-cpp that you are using?

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-05-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ferre](https://answers.ros.org/users/4789/ferre/) on 2013-05-06**:
Hi William, my version yaml-cpp is 0.5.1

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-06**:
@ferre that is definitely the problem then, you need to use yaml-cpp version 0.3.x with ROS. If you can find a way to get our code working with 0.5.x of yaml-cpp I would review a pull request to that end.